# Multiple Markers at this line, Java constructor error (beginner level).

Tags: java, eclipse, constructor

I just started to learn java and am not fimiliar with the language. this is an online assignment i am doing for fun and to get more fimiliar, and can't figure out the multiple errors i am getting with the constructor line. Please help

```
 public class WhackAMole {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   int score;
   int molesLeft;
   int attemptsLeft;
   char [][]moleGrid=new char[10][10];
   int numAttempts; //is this needed 
   int gridDimensions; // is this also needed 

   /*Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token "int", delete this token
- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
- Syntax error on token "int", delete this token
- numAttempts cannot be resolved to a variable
- gridDimensions cannot be resolved to a variable
- Syntax error on token "int", delete this token
- The method WhackAMole(int, int) is undefined for the type 
 WhackAMole*/
     WhackAMole(int numAttempts, int gridDimensions) {
      this.numAttempts=numAttempts ;  //error-cannot use this in static content
      this.gridDimensions=gridDimensions ; // error-cannot use this in static content

}

}

}
```

Comment: you aren't closing your main method. After `int gridDimensions;` add a `}` and remove 1 `}` from below.

Comment: You have to move the constructor and your fields out of `main`

Comment: You're mixing method and the constructor.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 3):

Move your constructor out of main() method.

Comment: Not just the constructor. He needs to move the attributes, too. He uses the variables in the constructor

Answer (score 2):

I reccomend you to do some basic beginner level java tutorial. You cannot put the constructor in another method (it's in the main method). Also to use this.numAttempts you need object Attributes. I tried to move the code-snippets to give it more sense:

```
public class WhackAMole {

    // Those are attributes
    private int score;
    private int molesLeft;
    private int attemptsLeft;
    private char[][] moleGrid = new char[10][10];
    private int numAttempts; // is this needed
    private int gridDimensions; // is this also needed

    // Constructor
    public WhackAMole(int numAttempts, int gridDimensions) {
        this.numAttempts = numAttempts;
        this.gridDimensions = gridDimensions;
    }

    public void play() {
        // Game logic here
    }

    /* This Method should propably be in another class */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final WhackAMole wham = new WhackAMole(42, 1234567);
        wham.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this assignment was from begning level class only ... will keep trying

Answer (score 1):

You were definining method inside a method which is not allowed in java. Also, I have moved the attributes to class level.

Please use below code:

```
public class WhackAMole {

    int score;
    int molesLeft;
    int attemptsLeft;
    char[][] moleGrid = new char[10][10];
    int numAttempts; //is this needed
    int gridDimensions; // is this also needed

    WhackAMole(final int numAttempts, final int gridDimensions) {
        this.numAttempts = numAttempts; //error-cannot use this in static content
        this.gridDimensions = gridDimensions; // error-cannot use this in static content
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        WhackAMole whackAMole = new WhackAMole(30, 40);
        System.out.println("numAttempts:" + whackAMole.numAttempts + " gridDimensions:" + whackAMole.gridDimensions);
    }
}
```

Comment: i noticed that you uysed final int in constructor, how is it different from int?